# Recursive function type based on object keys

Tags: node.js, typescript

Im trying to create a recursive function type that takes the outer most keys in an object type as an argument and returns a new function that then takes the next outer most keys of the object from the given key recursively until no more keys are available.

If the key doesn't extend `/${string}` the argument must be of an object type containing the key ans and property:

```js
type Argument<T> = T extends `/${string}` ? T : { [key in T]: string | number }
```

**There will only be one key that wont extend `/${string}` per. level.**

### Example

```js
const values = {
    '/aaa': {
        '/lorem': {
            foo: 'hello world',
            '/boo': 12345,
        },
    },

    bbb: {
        '/ipsum': {
            '/dolor': 'lorem ipsum',
            amet: 567890,
        },
    },

    '/ccc': ...
};

foo<typeof values>('/aaa')('/lorem')({ foo: '...' }); // should return type of string
foo<typeof values>('/aaa')('/lorem')('/boo'); // should return type of number
foo<typeof values>('/aaa')('/ipsum'); // should fail

foo<typeof values>({ bbb: '...' })('/ipsum')({ amet: '...' }); // should return type of number
foo<typeof values>({ bbb: '...' })('/ipsum')('/dolor'); // should return type of string
foo<typeof values>({ bbb: '...' })('/lorem'); // should fail
```

### My current code

I have a type that almost does the job., but doesn't work with the non `/${string}` extensions :(

```js
type Foo<T extends object> = <K extends keyof T>(args: K) => T[K] extends object ? Foo<T[K]> : T[K];

const values = {
    '/aaa': {
        '/lorem': {
            foo: 'hello world',
            '/boo': 12345,
        },
    },

    bbb: {
        '/ipsum': {
            '/dolor': 'lorem ipsum',
            amet: 567890,
        },
    },
};


const foo = {} as Foo<typeof values>

foo('/aaa')('/lorem')('/boo') // works :D
foo('/aaa')('/lorem')({ foo: '...' }) // fails :(
```

I tried to handle the args type within the function - But it can't return the next keys :(

```js
type Foo<T extends object> = <K extends keyof T>(
    args: K extends `/${string}` ? K : { [key in K]: string | number }
) => T[K] extends object ? Foo<T[K]> : T[K];

const values = {
    '/aaa': {
        '/lorem': {
            foo: 'hello world',
            '/boo': 12345,
        },
    },

    bbb: {
        '/ipsum': {
            '/dolor': 'lorem ipsum',
            amet: 567890,
        },
    },
};


const foo = {} as Foo<typeof values>

foo('/aaa')('/lorem')('/boo') // works :D
const a = foo({ bbb: '...' })('/ipsum') // fails :(
```

I don't even know if want I'm trying is possible - but if you have any suggestions you would save my day :)
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Thanks @MoritzRingler - unfortunately this doesn't work :( `const a = foo({ bbb: '...' })('/ipsum')` gives me `Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'. ` - My theoretical solution would be to extract the key that doesn't extend `/${string}` and somehow define that as `K` but it's a bit complicated 

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/N9bkJm) using overloads meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Hi @jcalz - Nice answer! - There is one problem with your solution, when I create and object as an argument it dosn't tell me what the key should be called :) It would help alot if you are in a different file and can't see the values object. I already accepted the answer below - but if you can solve it I would be glad to post a new question you could get credit for :)

Comment: Is [this](https://tsplay.dev/mbK53W) what you're looking for?

Comment: Hi @jcalz I'm at work so arn't fully available :)

It is almost there - even closert than before  I want to exclude keys from the objects that extends `/${string}` - Can you implement something like this? ```export type OmitSlashStrings<T> = {
 [K in keyof T as T[K] extends `/${string}` ? never : K]: T[K];
};```

Thanks again :)

Comment: Maybe [this](https://tsplay.dev/WJ7bgw)?  I'm not super thrilled to be doing so much extra fiddling with followup versions of code in the comment section of a question that's already accepted an answer that doesn't actually meet the requirements in the question, so I hope this exchange will conclude soon.

Comment: It works perfect! - Sorry for the trouble. I will be glad to post a new question so you can submit the solution to it :) You really saved my day! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, problem seems to be with `{[key in K]: string | number}`, apparently typescript does not know if `T[K]` is an object after that.
If you change it to `{[key: string]: K}` it works (but `{[key: string|number]: K}` does not). This seems like an issue with Typescript (I am using version 4.7.4.)

Best I can do is using a second parameter instead of an object:

```js
type Foo<T extends object> = <K extends keyof T>(
  arg: K,
  val?: K extends `/${string}` ? undefined : string|number
) => T[K] extends object ? Foo<T[K]> : T[K];


const foo = {} as Foo<typeof values>

const boo = foo('/aaa')('/lorem')('/boo') // TS: boo is number
const ipsum = foo('bbb', 12)('/ipsum') // TS: ipsum is Foo<{'/dolor': string, amet: number}>
```

Comment: Thanks - not 100% what I was looking for but I think this will work jsut fine :D

Comment: I made a little adjustment so the second argument only will be shown if a value is needed - let me know if you ever figure out how to define it like described above :)

```typescript
type Foo<T extends object> = <K extends keyof T>(
 ...args: K extends `/:${string}` ? [K, string | number] : [K]
) => T[K] extends object ? Foo<T[K]> : T[K];
```

Thanks again you help me alot! :)

Comment: Oh, that looks very nice! I think your initial declaration is absolutely correct and should work, but doesn't because of a bug in TS or a technical limitation. When you play around with the type of the object argument, you get really weird, unintentional behavior (might warrant a [bug report](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues)), My guess is that it will get fixed in a future TS version and it is one of those "you had the answer all along" situations

Comment: Haha thanks - I spend alot of time loosing my mind with this one . You are welcome to create a bug report - my english isn't that great so the problem might not even be understood  - Lets hope it will come in the future, cheers and thanks again